# CSS Apply border to all input elements except checkbox

Tags: css

I have a css class:

```
input {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #003399;
}
```

Which works for most of what I want but I now need to have a checkbox that doesn't have this border while the rest of the input elements on the page continue to have the border applied.

I therefore created the additional css class:

```
input[type="checkbox"] 
{
    border: none;
}
```

This works fine with FireFox and Chrome but not ie 8, an when I use the Developer Tools in ie to inspect the element I can see both styles have been picked up but it's only when I deselect the check box beside the input style does the border disappear for the check boxes.

This is the default:

[image]

And this is what I do to get rid of the border:

[image]

Comment: did you evaluate the possibiliy to use javascript for managing that? in IE the attribute selectors are a bit buggy (and till version 7 they weren't supported)

Comment: What happens if you specify no border for all inputs and then add them to the inputs you want?

Comment: It appears to be a bug in the attribute selector handling. Using a class rather than the attribute selector makes it work fine. Note: it *does* work when you make sure there is a proper doctype, such as the simple <!doctype html>

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Why not just use the :not selector to invert the attribute selector?

```
input:not([type=checkbox])
{
    border: 1px solid #039;
}
```

If it is IE8 or before, you should probably use separate rules for the classes where you *do* want to set the border, as it doesn't support :not (or any of the good stuff).

Edit:

```
input[type=checkbox]
{
    border: none;
}
```

works in IE8 if you add a doctype, even the simple <!doctype html>

Comment: Tried that but with input:not([type=checkbox]) none of the input have the desired border applied.

Comment: IE attribute selector parsing is cruddy. It's also the cause of your root probleem. If you use a class rather than the attribute selector or when you make sure there is a proper doctype, such as the simple <!doctype html>, the border:none override works just fine.

Comment: Applying a class direct to the check box works perfect. Thanks Steven

Answer (score 0):

It seems to say `medium none`. You could try `border: 0px transparent;` to see if that make's a difference.

Comment: didn't make any difference MrMisterMan. I also tried input[type="checkbox"] 
{
 border-width: 0px;
 border-style:none;
}

Answer (score 0):

In IE it is not the border that you are seeing. It must be the highlighting due to the focus on the checkbox. Try to execute blur event on checkbox click it might help.

Answer (score 0):

does this help?

```
input[type="checkbox"] 
{
    border: none !important;
}
```

Comment: better to avoid `!important` as much possible